# Android tabs with swipe views

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

i have been using many **tabbed activity with swipe views** source codes from past 4 days but none is launching on my mobile...and i am not getting the root cause of it
now i am using this [Aid Code](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/create-viewpager-tabs-android/#.Wc5qrluCzIV) and following all steps still my app is not launching....
sharing my code plz check the problem...or else guide me to something

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Add Fragments to adapter one by one
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "FRAG1");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "FRAG2");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), "FRAG3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}



// Adapter for the viewpager using FragmentPagerAdapter
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Fragment code

public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

```
public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post a crash log?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin no logs are shown...everything is compiling good...but app is not launching in mobile...have tried different mobile as well...but in vein

Comment: You mean app is not getting installed on the phone?

Comment: Can you post manifest.xml?

Comment: @SuhaylSH can say so...when i click on run button all processes are done gradle built and all...give me no errors or logs either...but just gives me a flash of white screen on mobile and then it closes in seconds..

Comment: @DimaKozhevin posted menifest.xml

Comment: @ZainabZafar your manifest.xml seems good at the first sight. You should post here your LogCat when you tried start app.

Comment: @DimaKozhevin thanku so very much for ur help....but http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/10/android-action-bar-tabs-swipe-views.html  code just worked perfect for me....finally this code launched giving me NO problem

Comment: @DimaKozhevin thanku once again for for helping me....